# What were these artifacts in Skin Game?

Tags: the-dresden-files

I know it's been out for a while, but I was just re-listening to Skin Game and realized I could not identify all the referenced artifacts found

> In Hades vault

Some were easy, some less so.  Any ideas?

For the record they were:

- “ancient wooden placard”
- a “circlet woven from thorny branches”,
- a “clay cup”,
- a “folded cloth”, and
- a “knife with a wooden handle and a leaf-shaped blade”

I don't have the quote handy, but I recall that they were all related to the crucifixion of Christ in some fashion.

The ones revealed in the text are:

> the cup is the Holy Grail

and

> the folded cloth is the Shroud of Turin

I figure the circlet is the Crown of Thorns placed on Christ's head by the romans, and I assume that the wooden placard with faded inscriptions reads INRE (allegedly a label placed on him as well, for the latin for Jesus of Nazareth, King of the Jews), but those are guesses.  I originally thought the "knife" was actually the tip of the Spear of Longinius, but it's described pretty consistently as a knife rather than just a blade.

Those are my guesses, though; do we have anything else that I missed in the text or from interviews, etc?

Comment: Just for reference, the wooden sign comes up again in *Battle Ground* and is exactly what you say it is.

Comment: Yep, read and enjoyed, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you've got them all right, save the knife.

As for that, I believe it's Jesus's bread knife. Quoth [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relics_associated_with_Jesus)

> According to French traveler Jules-Léonard Belin the knife used by Jesus to slice bread was permanently exhibited in the Logetta (decorated entrance hall) of St Mark's Campanile in Venice.

So clearly this knife is of some importance in certain corners of Christianity.

Comment: In the absence of Word of Jim, I'm going to accept this as the answer.

Comment: @Paul - This is now revealed in Battle Ground.

Answer (score 6):

All artifacts associated with Jesus Christ:

- “ancient wooden placard” - Placard "Jesus, King of the Jews", from his crucifixion.
- “circlet woven from thorny branches” - Crown of Thorns, from this 
  crucifixion.
- “clay cup” - The Holy Grail.
- “folded cloth” - The actual Shroud of Turin.
- “knife with a wooden handle and a leaf-shaped blade” The remains of the Holy Spear (the Spear of Destiny, or the Lance of Longinus), that pierced Christ's side during his crucifixion.  It is often described to have a leaf shaped blade, similar to many descriptions of Roman spears.

Edit: Little more homework:

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Lance):
In 615, Jerusalem and its relics were captured by the Persian forces of King Khosrau II (Chosroes II). According to the Chronicon Paschale, the point of the lance, which had been *broken off*, was given in the same year to Nicetas, who took it to Constantinople and deposited it in the church of Hagia Sophia, and later to the Church of the Virgin of the Pharos. This point of the lance, which was now set in an icon, was acquired by the Latin Emperor, Baldwin II of Constantinople, who later sold it to Louis IX of France. The point of the lance was then enshrined with the crown of thorns in the Sainte Chapelle in Paris. During the French Revolution these relics were removed to the Bibliothèque Nationale but *the point subsequently disappeared*.

(Italicised emphasis mine)

We know in the Dresden Files that Hades collects relics to keep them safe, and out of the hands of the unworthy. Maybe he was in France during the Revolution. We've seen evidence in the Dresden Files of ancient weapons being reworked (See the Swords of the Cross), perhaps the missing point of the Spear was worked into a knife.

Comment: I of course considered the spear of Longinus, but from the description it sounds like a knife. I can’t imagine that Harry wouldn’t know the different between a spear tip and a knife. And given that there’s meaningful knife in Christian lore/

Comment: And further, I’d expect that Harry would have heard of the Lance of Longinus in particular. So if he still thought it was a knife, it probably was a knife.

Comment: It’s not very easy to mistake the head  of a Roman spear for a knife. Take a look at these Roman spear heads: http://www.ebay.com/bhp/roman-spear. There’d be an iron shaft extending down from the tip, and all in all it wouldn’t look like a knife to anyone even mildly acquainted with spears.

Comment: I struggle to reconcile Jesus's bread knife sitting in an /armoury/ next to other objects from his Crucifixion. Yes, I get that the cup he drank from at the last supper is there, but at least that has an incredible amount of lore associated with it.

Comment: And so is the shroud, the crown of thorns, the placard...none of these are traditional weapons. They have power because of their association with Jesus.

Comment: @Adamant The power is less because of an association with Jesus, then the belief and faith held in these items by the population. That's how Harry explains the 'Shroud of Turin' from Death Masks still having power. Until a little while ago, I'd never heard of the bread knife, but recognized the Placard, crown, cup and shroud immediately.

Comment: Not in this case, at least not directly. The fake shroud of Turin had power because people had faith in it. The one in the vault of Hades is implied to be the original, which has power because, well, it’s the real Shroud of Turin, and was in contact with a being of power in a certain situation. Whether that power indirectly comes from faith…possibly. I am not sure, though: the Judeo-Christo-Islamic (and others?) God seems to be portrayed as being on a different level from some of the old pagan deities, who *are* empowered by faith.

Comment: Though it’s not impossible that having billions of believers is simply better than having a few thousand, like Hades probably does. But that’s not the impression I got.

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait an see; I'm with @Adamant though that it seems like an easier answer that it's a knife from the last supper than a reworked speartip.  Occam's leaf blade, as it were. ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Abraham's knife, possibly

The **knife with a wooden handle and a leaf-shaped blade** may be the knife that Abraham almost used to sacrifice his son Isaac ([Genesis 22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2022&version=NIV)).

Leaf-shaped daggers<sup>(1)</sup> were in use in the Middle East around the time of Abraham and Isaac<sup>(2)</sup>.  The other items in Hades' vault – placard, circlet, cup, and cloth – pertain to Jesus' crucifixion, and a prominent Christian interpretation of the [Binding of Isaac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_of_Isaac#Christian_views) draws parallels between Abraham and God the Father, in that they were each willing to sacrifice their sons, as well as between Isaac and Jesus, both of whom chose to submit to their fathers' plans.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> [Dagger with Leaf-shaped Blade, 2500 - 2000 BCE](https://www.dia.org/art/collection/object/dagger-leaf-shaped-blade-53049).  (Although the handle of this particular dagger is not wooden, that's a minor detail compared to the blade style.  It's reasonable to suppose that similarly-shaped daggers from that time and place used a variety of handle materials.)

<sup>(2)</sup> A quick Google search gives the date of Isaac's birth as [1896 BC](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20year%20was%20isaac%20born) [BCE].  This search method is probably good enough for a rough approximation, which is all we need here.